# Django: Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, django

I am trying to remove items from cart using `Jquery` and `Django`, I have written the logic to do this but I keep getting this errror that says `Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable`, I can seem to know what the problem is because I have tried converting the code below to list using `list()` method in django and also `values()` but it still does not work as expected.

**views.py**

```
def RemoveWishlist(request):
    wishlist = Wishlist.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    ...
    context = {
        "bool":True,
        "wishlist":wishlist
    }
    t = render_to_string('core/async/wishlist-list.html', context)
    return JsonResponse({'data':t,'wishlist':wishlist})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error mentions, queryset is not JSON serializable. Hence you can make it into JSON using [Django's serializers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/serialization/#serializing-data) and pass it to JsonResponse class initiation:

```
from django.core import serializers
....
qs_json = serializers.serialize('json', wishlist)
return JsonResponse({'data':t,'wishlist':qs_json})
```